# Добавление атрибута к DOM-элементу (php/DOMDocument/simpleXML)

Tags: xml, php, dom

Такая задача:

1. Получаю от web-сервиса xml.
2. Нужно к изображению добавить атрибут title.

Проблема в том, что с помощью DOMDocument я этого сделать не могу, т.к. не нахожу такого метода (поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Поэтому я делаю это с помощью simpleXML. Однако при обратной конвертации этот атрибут не сохраняется. К сожалению, опыта работы с XML у меня очень мало, сам найти ошибку (или, может быть, лучшее решение) не могу. Наверняка оно есть и очевидно для профессионала в этой области. Вот примерный код:

```
$html='
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xml:lang="ru-ru" lang="ru-ru">
    <head>
    </head>
    <div id="original">
        <a href="javascript:void();"><img src="images/apply_f2.png" id="first"></a>
    </div> 
    </body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument(); // создаём новый объект DOMDocument
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$origin=$doc->getElementById('original');
$a=$origin->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
$img=$a->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0); // получаем нужный элемент (изображение)

$image=new SimpleXMLElement($doc->saveXML($img)); // создаём новый объект SimpleXMLElement
$image->addAttribute('title', 'the IMAGE is here'); // добавляем атрибут title изображению

$timage = dom_import_simplexml($image); // конвертируем объект SimpleXMLElement в DOMDocument
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае решение в том, чтобы использовать преобразование дважды -

```
$image=simplexml_import_dom($img);
$image->addAttribute('title', 'the IMAGE is here');
dom_import_simplexml($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Без `SimpleXMLElement` как то так:

```
$attribute = $doc -> createAttribute("title");
$attribute -> value = "the IMAGE is here";
$img -> setAttributeNode($attribute);
```